Can HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync(); throw an exception?
In my application i inherited some code and i see this construct;
string? content = null;
try
{
    content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
}
catch(Exception e) when (e is not OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Swallow
}

Is this superfluous? Can ReadAsStringAsync throw anything other than OperationCancelledException or can the catch be removed assuming the OperationCancelledException is caught up the chain?
The msdn docs do not show any exceptions other than OperationCancelledException.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=net-8.0

"Is this superfluous?" - Depends on what the initial purpose was / is. So, you'll probably need to track down the original author of that piece of code. If you get an answer, let us know. I'd be interested in the reasoning, here.

aside from ReadAsStringAsync, this code can at least throw a null ref exception (if result is null)

The content is interpreted as string here. So there are a gazillion of possible encoding errors lurking. Then HttpContent could be disposed already. Your system might have a resource problem so all possible sorts of Out of Resource problems might occur. And many many more.

The try...catch is fine, but the "swallow" is not

For example, the server might disconnect after sending only half of the string. Or your network connection might drop. The string data might be improperly encoded. The content-type header might be invalid. The content-encoding might be an unsupported compression format. So many things could go wrong. It's really a miracle that anything works at all.
